# Q: How to prove $A^{\circ}=A^{c-c}$

Tags: general-topology

I can only prove the special case of when $A$ is open : $A$ is open $\Rightarrow A=A^{\circ}$ ; $A^{c}$ is closed $\Rightarrow A^{c-}=A^c$; so, $A^{c-c}=A^{cc}=A=A^{\circ}$. I have difficulty in proving the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try element-chasing to show that each side is a subset of the other.

Suppose that $x\in\operatorname{int}A$; then $\operatorname{int}A$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $X\setminus A$, so $x\notin \operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, and therefore $x\in X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$. This shows that

$$\operatorname{int}A\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)\;.$$

Can you now use a similar technique to show the opposite inclusion?

Comment: Since $A^{c-c}$ is open, I finally get that $A^{c-c}\subseteq A^{c-cc-c}=A^{c--c}=A^{c-c}$, not the desired $A^{c-c}\subseteq A^{\circ}$

Comment: @yushang: Try following my suggestion. Let $V=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, and start with an arbitrary $x\in V$. $V$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and $V$ is disjoint from $X\setminus A$, so $V\subseteq\ldots$?

Comment: @brian-m-scott. By your first part I got $A^{\circ}\subseteq A^{c-c}$; on the other hand, $A^{c}\subseteq A^{c-} \Rightarrow A\supseteq A^{c-c} \Rightarrow A^{\circ}\subseteq A^{c-c}\subseteq A$, since $A^{c-c}$ is open and $A^{\circ}$ is the largest open set in $A$, got $A^{\circ}=A^{c-c}$.

Comment: @yushang: Yes, that will do it.